# Using Imagga API and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I was trying to upload an image to IMAGGA API and get back some image recognition tags for my project but I am not able to get the desired tags. I have used Alamofire to upload the image but I ma getting this error and no tags from the API call.

Here is the function which I have used to upload the image.
Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            defer {
                picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            }

            print(info)
            // get the image
            guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
                return
            }

            imageView.image = image


            let documentDirectory: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as NSString

            let imageName = "temp"
            let imagePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)

            if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 80) {
                // Save cloned image into document directory
                let urlFile = NSURL(string: imagePath)

                do {
                    try data.write(to: urlFile! as URL, options: .atomic)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                // Save it's path
                localPath = imagePath
            }

            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

    //

            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Authorization": "Basic YWNjX2MwNDUzYzkzNTEyOGNkYzo0ZmE5MWM4Zjg0MDk1ZGI0NGE2ZjNjODJkNTczZDUxOQ==",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            ]

            Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\("acc_c0453c935128cdc")/\("4fa91c8f84095db44a6f3c82d573d519")", parameters: ["url": "http://docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg"], headers: headers)
                .authenticate(user: "acc_c0453c935128cdc", password: "4fa91c8f84095db44a6f3c82d573d519")
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    switch(response.result) {
                    case .success(_):
                        if let data = response.result.value{


                            print("YOUR JSON DATA>>  \(response.data!)")


                        }
                        break

                    case .failure(_):
                        print(response.result.error)


                        break

                    }

            }



        }
```

I am getting this as the error. It's showing success at the end but I am not sure whether the image is sent to the imagga for image recognition or not.

```
Error:

    URL which has no scheme
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D8A0EE1D-2092-474F-B21A-8A7E0635AD40/Documents/temp}
    [Request]: GET https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/acc_c0453c935128cdc/4fa91c8f84095db44a6f3c82d573d519?url=http%3A//docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg
    [Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1702210e0> { URL: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/acc_c0453c935128cdc/4fa91c8f84095db44a6f3c82d573d519?url=http%3A//docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg } { status code: 200, headers {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
        Connection = "keep-alive";
        "Content-Length" = 62;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json";
        Date = "Tue, 29 Aug 2017 16:42:07 GMT";
        Server = "meinheld/0.6.1";
        Via = "1.1 vegur";
        "X-Powered-By" = Flask;
        "X-Processed-Time" = "0.000633001327515";
    } }
    [Data]: 62 bytes
    [Result]: SUCCESS: {
        authenticated = 1;
        user = "acc_c0453c935128cdc";
    }
    [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 525717726.320, "Initial Response Time": 525717728.876, "Request Completed Time": 525717728.882, "Serialization Completed Time": 525717728.889, "Latency": 2.556 secs, "Request Duration": 2.562 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.006 secs, "Total Duration": 2.569 secs }
    YOUR JSON DATA>>  62 bytes
```

Comment: Never post api keys on public forums.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because your parameters is not encoded correctly. Your question mentions Imagga but you are using httpbin for debugging.

Here's a working example of Alamofire + Imagga's API:

## Using a remote image

```
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "version" : 2,
        "url" : "http://playground.imagga.com/static/img/example_photo.jpg"
    ]
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    ]

    // Three ways to add the auth header (3rd is to use authenticate method):
    //    1. Append the basic encoded value already provided by Imagga's dashboard
    // headers["Authorization"] = "Basic xxxxxx=="
    //    2. Construct the header using the api key + api secret
    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: "api_ley", password: "api_secret") {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    Alamofire
        .request("http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
    }
```

Response:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "tagging_id": null,
      "image": "http://playground.imagga.com/static/img/example_photo.jpg",
      "tags": [
        {
          "confidence": 71.4296152834829,
          "tag": "beach"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 52.843097989562466,
          "tag": "sea"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 46.13550857065488,
          "tag": "sun"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 43.923454585374714,
          "tag": "ocean"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 43.23227098537762,
          "tag": "water"
        },
        {
          "confidence": 7.113114870093362,
          "tag": "leisure"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

## Uploading a local image

As the documentation mentions, you need to upload the image to the `content` endpoint first.

Simple response structs to make JSON parsing easier (Swift 4. Should be easy enough to use Swift 3, but more tedious):

```
struct ImaggaContentResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let message: String?
    let uploaded: [ImaggaContent]

    struct ImaggaContent: Decodable {
        let id, filename: String
    }
}


/// Represents the available sources for images
///
/// - url: Represents a remote images (URL must be specified)
/// - content: Represents a previously uploaded local image to the content endpoint (content id must be provided)
enum ImaggaImageOrigin {
    case url(String)
    case content(String)
}
```

Sample:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var headers: HTTPHeaders = {
        var defaultheaders = [
            "Accept" : "application/json"
        ]
        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: "api_key", password: "api_secret") {
            defaultheaders[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        return defaultheaders
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageData = UIImage.make(from: .purple).jpeg!
        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        to: "https://api.imagga.com/v1/content",
        method: .post,
        headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print(progress)
                })
                upload.responseData { response in
                    guard let jsonData = response.value,
                        let contentResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ImaggaContentResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                        else { return }

                    let firstImage = contentResponse.uploaded.first!
                    self.tagImage(from: .content(firstImage.id))
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print (encodingError)
            }
        })
    }

    func tagImage(from source: ImaggaImageOrigin) {
        var parameters: Parameters = [
            "version" : 2,
        ]

        switch source {
        case .url(let imageUrl):
            parameters["url"] = imageUrl
        case .content(let contentId):
            parameters["content"] = contentId
        }

        Alamofire
            .request("http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseString { (response) in
                print(response)
        }
    }
}
```